# Проверка на существование web-страницы (visual c#)

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование

Как проверить web-страницу (в моем случае изображение) на существование/доступность? Можно, конечно, просто загружать её и обрабатывать исключение в виде возврата ошибки 404 конструкцией try-catch, но не уверен что это самый удачный способ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ проверить сущестовование ресурса - сделать HEAD-запрос. Ответ на HEAD полностью совпадает с ответом на обычный GET, но без тела запроса:

```
WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
try
{
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exists");
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not exists: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

можно так

```
var serverFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/folder/filename.jpg");
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(serverFilePath);
if(!fileInfo.Exists)
{
    // файла нет
}
```

Но это валидно если с файлом хотите работать на стороне сервера. Для клиента все-таки лучше 404 отработать

**UPD:** Есть еще вариант вызывать загрузку картинок не напрямую а с помощью хандлера, который и будет проверять наличие по описанной выше схеме

Answer (score 1):

У объекта HttpWebResponse есть свойство StatusCode, также его можно проверять, чтобы конкретизировать статусный код и состояние ответа